# Sort table data with Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have setup a component using Angular and Material. I have the data I want exposed correctly using the BitBucket status API: 
https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/api#status

I am just stuck on how to enable sort on the columns, I would like to sort all 3 using the default settings. Any direction would be appreciated.

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmdy9j

HTML:

```
<div class="example-table-container">

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data"
           matSort matSortActive="name" matSortDirection="desc">


      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.status}}</td>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="created_at">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
          Created
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.created_at | date}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

  </div>
```

TS:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material';
import {merge, Observable, of as observableOf} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, map, startWith, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-headlines',
  templateUrl: './headlines.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./headlines.component.scss']
})

export class HeadlinesComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'status', 'created_at'];
  tableDatabase: TableHttpDatabase | null;
  data: BitBucketIssue[] = [];

  resultsLength = 0;
  isLoadingResults = true;


  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tableDatabase = new TableHttpDatabase(this.http);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.tableDatabase!.getRepoIssues(
            this.sort.active, this.sort.direction);
        }),
        map(data => {

          // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.incidents.length;
          console.log(data.incidents.length)
          console.log(data.incidents)
          return data.incidents;

        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }
}

export interface BitBucketApi {
  incidents: BitBucketIssue[];
}

export interface BitBucketIssue {
  name: string;
  status: string;
  created_at: number;
}

/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class TableHttpDatabase {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getRepoIssues(sort: string, order: string): Observable<BitBucketApi> {
    const href = 'https://bqlf8qjztdtr.statuspage.io/api/v2/incidents.json';
    const requestUrl =
        `${href}?q=&sort=${sort}&order=${order}`;

    return this.http.get<BitBucketApi>(requestUrl);
  }
}
```

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmdy9j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you were not linking the required *MatTableDataSource* to your retrieved data.
You need to assign your *MatSort* element to the *MatTableDataSource* sort property, and use the *MatTableDataSource* to display the data. All well documented in the official documentation https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview

**ANGULAR CODE**

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {merge, Observable, of as observableOf} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, map, startWith, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

/**
 * @title Table retrieving data through HTTP
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-http-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-http-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-http-example.html',
})
export class TableHttpExample implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'status', 'created_at'];
  tableDatabase: TableHttpDatabase | null;
  data: BitBucketIssue[] = [];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<BitBucketIssue>;

  resultsLength = 0;
  isLoadingResults = true;


  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tableDatabase = new TableHttpDatabase(this.http);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.tableDatabase!.getRepoIssues(
            this.sort.active, this.sort.direction);
        }),
        map(data => {

          // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.incidents.length;
          console.log(data.incidents.length)
          console.log(data.incidents)
          return data.incidents;

        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data; this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }
}

export interface BitBucketApi {
  incidents: BitBucketIssue[];
}

export interface BitBucketIssue {
  name: string;
  status: string;
  created_at: number;
}

/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class TableHttpDatabase {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getRepoIssues(sort: string, order: string): Observable<BitBucketApi> {
    const href = 'https://bqlf8qjztdtr.statuspage.io/api/v2/incidents.json';
    const requestUrl =
        `${href}?q=&sort=${sort}&order=${order}`;

    return this.http.get<BitBucketApi>(requestUrl);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="example-table-container">

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"
           matSort matSortActive="name" matSortDirection="desc">

      <!-- Title Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- State Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.status}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Created Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="created_at">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
          Created
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.created_at | date}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

  </div>
```